# Gnus: Don't show negatively scored articles

Tags: gnus

I use a Gnus score file to mark certain Usenet articles that I don't want to read. For example, a line from my `$HOME/News/name.of.newsgroup.SCORE` might look something like:

```
("troll@example.com" -1000 nil e)
```

When I enter the newsgroup, articles from that user are marked as read, but they still show up in the list of articles in the Summary buffer.

It's easy enough to type `x` (`gnus-summary-limit-to-unread`) to remove those articles from the list, but is there a way to configure Gnus so I don't see them in the first place?

If so, is it also possible to configure my score file so that *some* articles are not shown at all, while others are shown but automatically marked as read? (For example, I might assign a larger negative score to articles I don't want to see at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the variable `gnus-summary-expunge-below` to control below which score not to show.

I have set it to -9999 and I score articles I don't want to even appear in the Summary buffer -10000.

Articles I want automatically read, but still shown in the Summary, I usually score at -5000.

Comment: Before trying this, I found that I had `(expunge -1001)` at the bottom of my `.SCORE` file. Changing a score from the default `-1000` to `-2000` does the trick.

Comment: More details: with my current setup (which I think is close to the default), typing "laep" (lower score, by author, exact match, permanent) lowers the score for that author's articles by 1000, causing them to be automatically marked as read. Typing "laep" *again* lowers the score by 1000 again, causing that author's articles to be hidden entirely.